# Apparent bug in the way office-js reads the filter of a pivot table

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to use office-js to read which items in a pivot table filter have been selected by the user.  When the user selects a single value (without checking the "select multiple items" check box) as shown here:

[image: Pivot Table set to show a single value]

The pivot table's filterHierarchies-->fields will show each items visible property as true--even though only one is selected.

If the same filter is selected but the "select multiple items" check box is checked as shown here

[image: Pivot Table set to show a single value]

The visible property will be reported correctly.

I have published an addin along with a workbook that demonstrates the issue at github:

[Addin demonstrating issue](https://github.com/theGove/js_bug_demo)

My hope is that the office js team at Microsoft will verify that this is a bug and work to correct it.  If this behavior is expected, I'd like to learn how to tell which item in a pivot table filter is selected when the "select multiple items" check box is not checked.

Comment: If you are confident you found a bug, I'd suggest to post it as an issue on GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues